# Labels of PieChart does not fit

Tags: codenameone

I used a PieChart in an CodenameOne App and found out, that the labels does not fit on the screen on my iPhone (see screenshot). It's ok on an iPad - but not on smaller devices. I know that I can set a scale-factor - but I think there is no scale factor that fits well for all device sizes.

Is there any solution for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label sizes based on millimeter sizes by using `convertToPixels` from `Display` or `CN`. This might not be enough though and you might need to have some special cases to get charts working properly on all devices. You can use features like `isTablet` and `getDensity` to tune the behavior to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the PieChart, you have a few options here:

1. Use the renderer's setScale() method to scale the pie chart.  This should only affect the radius of the Pie.  The default is to make the pie radius 35% of the min(width,height) of the chart component.  If you scale it, it will apply that scale.    You could check the display width to determine what scale you're going to need so that you only scale on devices that need it.
2. Use a legend instead of showing the text labels. (i.e. renderer.setShowLegend(true).. and renderer.setShowLabels(false)).  Again you can do this selectively based on whether the device is a tablet or a phone.

Comment: Thanks for the tips :-)